# Cannot save managed object with all attributes set

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, xcode5

I am trying to get into Core Data. I also read most of the Apple Developer documentation relating to Core Data but I have a strange problem:

I created an Xcode project called "Wishes" using Core Data so most of the things got set up automatically. I set up my xcdatamodel like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<model userDefinedModelVersionIdentifier="" type="com.apple.IDECoreDataModeler.DataModel" documentVersion="1.0" lastSavedToolsVersion="5059" systemVersion="13B42" minimumToolsVersion="Automatic" macOSVersion="Automatic" iOSVersion="Automatic">
    <entity name="ListenWish" representedClassName="ListenWish" parentEntity="Wish" syncable="YES">
        <attribute name="album" optional="YES" attributeType="String" syncable="YES"/>
        <attribute name="artist" optional="YES" attributeType="String" syncable="YES"/>
        <attribute name="year" optional="YES" attributeType="Integer 16" defaultValueString="0" syncable="YES"/>
    </entity>
    <entity name="Wish" representedClassName="Wish" isAbstract="YES" syncable="YES">
        <attribute name="dateAdded" attributeType="Date" syncable="YES"/>
        <attribute name="dateModified" attributeType="Date" syncable="YES"/>
        <attribute name="rating" attributeType="Integer 16" minValueString="0" maxValueString="6" defaultValueString="0" syncable="YES"/>
        <attribute name="recommendedBy" attributeType="String" indexed="YES" syncable="YES"/>
        <attribute name="title" attributeType="String" maxValueString="64" indexed="YES" spotlightIndexingEnabled="YES" syncable="YES"/>
    </entity>
    <fetchRequest name="BiggestWishes" entity="Wish" predicateString="rating == 6"/>
    <elements>
        <element name="ListenWish" positionX="-63" positionY="-0" width="128" height="88"/>
        <element name="Wish" positionX="79" positionY="-190" width="128" height="120"/>
    </elements>
</model>
```

So there are basically **two entity descriptions: Wish & ListenWish**, while Wish is the parent entitity for ListenWish.

I have also set `NSManagedObject` subclasses for both of these.

Now in my view controller I am trying to **save a new managed object of type ListenWish** using textfields like this:

#### DDAddWishViewController.h:

```
@interface DDAddWishViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *artistField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *albumField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *yearField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *ratingSlider;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *recommendedByField;

@property (strong, nonatomic) ListenWish *wish;

- (IBAction)saveWish:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;

@end
```

#### DDAddWishViewController.m

```
...

DDAppDelegate *appDelegate = (DDAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

// Create a new managed object of type ListenWish
self.wish = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ListenWish" inManagedObjectContext:context];

self.wish.artist = self.artistField.text;
self.wish.album = self.albumField.text;
self.wish.year = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self.yearField.text integerValue]];

self.wish.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", self.wish.artist, self.wish.album]; // line A.
self.wish.rating = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.ratingSlider.value];
self.wish.recommendedBy = self.recommendedByField.text; // line B.

NSError *error = nil;
if ( [self.wish.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    //TODO: Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
    // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
    NSLog(@"Could not save to data store %@, %@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
```

Now the strange thing is: Everything **would work just as expected, but only if** I comment out either line A (assigning the title string) or line B (assigning the recommendedBy string).
In other words: if I **keep just *one* of those lines**, **everything works** (except that the saved data does not contain the respective string, of course), but if I want to **keep both of them, I get an error** when trying to save to the managedObjectContext: `Could not save to data store (null), (null)`

Also:
When I just **delete the attribute "recommendedBy"** using the Core Data Model Editor in Xcode and also delete every reference to it in Wish.h, Wish.m and of course in my view controller, after deleting the app and running it again **I get the same error**: `Could not save to data store (null), (null)`

What is wrong with my model? What am I doing wrong? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your check

```
if ( [self.wish.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
```

is wrong and should be

```
if (! [self.wish.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
```

because the `save` method returns `TRUE` if the save succeeded, and `NO` in the case of
an error. If you comment out one of your lines A or B then the save *fails* because the
"title" and "recommendedBy" attributes are not marked as optional.